# Нахождение корней уравнения методом дихотомии Java

Tags: java, алгоритм, функции, график

Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой:
*(краткая формулировка вопроса дана в самом конце)*
у меня имеется функция, например, такая: (`N = 1` для этого варианта)
[image: функция]
Их много разных, и все они такие "красивые".
График у неё ещё красивее:
[image: график]
Так вот, мне необходимо все точки пересечения графика с осью абсцисс (корни уравнения) выделить цветом, и найти эти корни методом дихотомии.
Сам алгоритм сложностей не вызвал:

```
    while (right - left > epsilon){
        tmp = (right - left)/2;

        if (get_Y_for_X(right) * get_Y_for_X(tmp) < 0) {
            left = tmp;
        } else {
            right = tmp;
        }

       root = (left + right)/2;
    }
```

Однако, мне нужно проделать это многократно, и найти каждый корень. Как я понимаю, с помощью данного алгоритма можно найти только один корень в заданном промежутке 
`[left, right]`. Значит, мне нужно знать все промежутки, в которых находятся корни, и уже в них искать? В общем, я не очень понимаю, как подойти к решению. Буду рад помощи. Возможно, я не увидел какого-то элементарного момента или не додумался до чего-то простого.

---

Думал следующим образом: раз с помощью алгоритма, написанного сверху, можно найти корень на заданном промежутке (в задании конкретно для этой функции у меня указан промежуток `[-4, 4]` и `epsilon = 0.0001`) то я могу разбить его на много промежутков, например, длиной в `l = 1` или `l = 0.5`, и на каждом найти эти корни, записать их и потом уже отметить на графике. То есть, добавлялся еще один цикл `while` сверх того алгоритма, и выполнялся он `длина промежутка / l` раз, и затем `left = предыдущий right`, `right = предыдущий right + l`, в общем, тут всё предельно просто, однако, опять же загвоздка в том, что корней на этих промежутках может быть гораздо больше одного, а может и не быть вообще. Ведь мне нужно не просто реализовать метод дихотомии, а найти **`все`** корни этим методом. К тому же, один пункт в задании меня немного озадачил: нужно будет, также, найти интеграл на промежутке от 2 до 3 корня на графике. Посмотрев на получившийся график, я так и не понял, откуда вести отсчёт, от левой границы или от нуля, и какой корень считать первым, чтобы найти второй и третий. В любом случае, получается не очень хорошо. В указаниях к заданию есть пример сделанной программы (крайне убогий), и, судя по графику, который с помощью неё нарисован, там была использована далеко не такая функция, какая дана в задании, и составители заданий не позаботились об этом. Либо, опять же, я где-то в начале не учёл что-то и зря ищу виноватых.

---

Для тех, кто напишет "оченьмногобукв", или как-то по-иному возмутится насчёт чрезмерно длинной формулировки вопроса: я всегда стараюсь как можно подробнее поставить вопрос, чтобы тем, кто захочет мне ответить, было всё понятно сразу, а также, стараюсь осветить все стороны своего вопроса. Но, всё же, сделаю ещё так:

Выше дана моя функция, мне нужно **`методом дихотомии`** найти **`все`** корни этого уравнения на промежутке `[-4, 4]` с точностью до `0.0001`. То есть, мне нужны `Х` и `Y` всех точек, которые будут корнями уравнения. Нуждаюсь в помощи с реализацией алгоритма по нахождению этих корней.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблему отделения корней в данном случае решает подстановка

**t = x<sup>4</sup> sign(x), x = |t|<sup>1/4</sup> sign(t),**

вид функции **z(t) = y(x(t))** приведён в скриншоте программы MathCAD

(интервал первого графика **x = [ - 4<sup>1/4</sup>, 4<sup>1/4</sup>]**):

[image: скриншот программы MathCAD]

Экстремумы функции **f(t) = sin 16t** достигаются в точках

**T<sub>i</sub> = (2i+1)*Pi/32**

и хорошо отделяют корни функции **z(t).**

Анализ значений экстремумов (таблица в скриншоте) с учётом равенства **z(0)=1** показывает, что на интервале **(0, 1.9) z(t)>0,** т.е. корней нет.

Следует учесть, что при **x = [-4,4]  t = [-256, 256].**

Comment: Все это хорошо, и довольно наглядно, однако до сих пор непонятно, как это реализовать на Java именно тем методом, которым мне нужно :)

Comment: @PeterSamokhin Интервалы для каждого корня по t известны, перевести их в интервалы по x нетрудно. Реализация вычисления корней на известных интервалах требуемым методом и на требуемом языке - уже Ваша задача :)

Comment: проблема решилась другим способом, но всё таки для этого графика я не очень понял: вы предложили разбить промежуток [-4, 4] на мелкие промежутки, длиной (2k+1)*Pi/32, и на них искать корни нужным мне методом?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin Я предложил разбить множество t  in ([-256, 0] | [1.9, 256]) на части длиной Pi/16 (около 2600 частей), перевести координаты границ из t в x (формула в тексте) и на преобразованных интервалах найти корни y(x) требуемым методом.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется,Если ты хочешь узнать абсолютно все корни уравнения, то можно сделать следующее:

```
Изначально взять 3 точки (left,right и temp),
где temp = left + 2*eps*k , k = 1,2,3,...,n и temp < right
```

Данную операцию нужно проделать только во время первого цикла, а дальше всё оставить как прежде. В итоге у тебя получится последовательность корней уравнения и сложность алгоритма будет O(nLogn).

Comment: Не совсем понял, можете показать на примере? Мне нужно, чтобы был использован именно метод дихотомии, и именно на данном в задании промежутке (от -4 до 4).

Comment: `for (int temp = left + 2*eps; temp< right; temp += 2*eps)
{
 int temp1 = temp
 if (get_Y_for_X(right) * get_Y_for_X(tmp) < 0) {
             left = tmp;
         } else {
             right = tmp;
         }

        root = temp;

 while (right - left > epsilon){
        tmp = (right - left)/2;

         if (get_Y_for_X(right) * get_Y_for_X(tmp) < 0) {
             left = tmp;
         } else {
             right = tmp;
         }

        root = (left + right)/2;
     }
}`

Comment: Я так понимаю, вы просто предлагаете разбирать промежуток [-4, 4] на много более мелких промежутков, длиной в epsilon, и находить корни в каждом из них более мелких промежутков? Такая идея и мне приходила, но программа не выполнится из-за чрезмерной нагрузки, и просто зависнет. А перебирать промежутки, просто отсекая каждый раз от начала промежутка по промежуток длиной epsilon, тоже не лучший вариант

Comment: К сожалению, ваш пример во 2 комментарии нарушает сам метод дихотомии, а также, я не уверен, что программа вовсе не зависнет.

Comment: попробуйте математически оптимизировать, предварительно посмотрев, где в каких точках функция будет иметь производную, равная нулю

Comment: К сожалению, ещё и производную сюда же подмешивать будет крайне нецелесообразно. Лишние расчёты, от которых вряд ли будет польза. Я бы мог просто перебрать каждую точку графика с шагом в epsilon на заданном промежутке, и тупо выбрать все точки, где y = 0. Возможно, и памяти это заняло бы не так много,  и так далее. Но это не соответствует заданию.

Comment: Программа не зависнет. Для вашего случая, она будет перебирать 4000 значений, что должно выполниться достаточно быстро

Comment: У меня получается 2600 корней. Даже если их отделить, объём вычислений значительный. При этом точность 0.0001 относится к y, а не к x.